# Android Assess Camera/Gallery on WebView?

Tags: android, webview, camera

I'm trying to use WebView on my Android Activity, the web works fine for Location and things, the only problem I have is it's not triggering up the open file chooser Intent for the upload button.

Here is my code. MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
private static final int FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE = 2888;
private WebView webView;
private ValueCallback<Uri> mUploadMessage;
private Uri mCapturedImageURI = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setActionBar();
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webViewNewBusiness);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this), "Android");
    webView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
    webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
    webView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
    webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);

    String serviceId = getIntent().getExtras().getString(Constant.SERVICE_ID);
    String userHash = PhoneData.getUserHash(this);
    String url = thisUrl;
    Log.d(TAG, url);
    final Activity activity = this;
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
            // Activities and WebViews measure progress with different scales.
            // The progress meter will automatically disappear when we reach 100%
            activity.setProgress(progress * 1000);
        }

        public void onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt(String origin, GeolocationPermissions.Callback callback) {
            callback.invoke(origin, true, false);
        }

        // openFileChooser for Android 3.0+
        public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType) {
            // Update message
            mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
            try {
                // Create AndroidExampleFolder at sdcard
                File imageStorageDir = new File(
                        Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "Pictures");
                if (!imageStorageDir.exists()) {
                    // Create AndroidExampleFolder at sdcard
                    imageStorageDir.mkdirs();
                }
                // Create camera captured image file path and name
                File file = new File(imageStorageDir + File.separator + "IMG_" + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg");
                mCapturedImageURI = Uri.fromFile(file);
                // Camera capture image intent
                final Intent captureIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                captureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mCapturedImageURI);
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                i.setType("image/*");
                // Create file chooser intent
                Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(i, "Image Chooser");
                // Set camera intent to file chooser
                chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS
                        , new Parcelable[]{captureIntent});
                // On select image call onActivityResult method of activity
                startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Exception:" + e, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

        // openFileChooser for Android < 3.0
        public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg) {
            openFileChooser(uploadMsg, "");
        }

        //openFileChooser for other Android versions
        public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg,
                                    String acceptType,
                                    String capture) {
            openFileChooser(uploadMsg, acceptType);
        }


        // The webPage has 2 filechoosers and will send a
        // console message informing what action to perform,
        // taking a photo or updating the file
        public boolean onConsoleMessage(ConsoleMessage cm) {
            onConsoleMessage(cm.message(), cm.lineNumber(), cm.sourceId());
            return true;
        }

        public void onConsoleMessage(String message, int lineNumber, String sourceID) {
            //Log.d("androidruntime", "Show console messages, Used for debugging: " + message);
        }

    });
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
            Log.d(activity, getString(R.string.generic_error));
        }
    });
    webView.loadUrl(url);
}

private void setActionBar() {
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    final ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
    if (ab != null) {
        ab.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ab_back);
        ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (webView.canGoBack()) {
        webView.goBack();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    if (requestCode == FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE) {
        if (null == this.mUploadMessage) {
            return;
        }
        Uri result = null;
        try {
            if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
                result = null;
            } else {
                // retrieve from the private variable if the intent is null
                result = intent == null ? mCapturedImageURI : intent.getData();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "activity :" + e,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(result);
        mUploadMessage = null;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: where is your upload button in code to call the openFileChooser function?

Comment: The upload button will on the webView the openFileChooser is not triggered up on clicking on upload button.

Comment: Perhaps post your html/javascript also

Comment: <input type="file" name="userfile" multiple>

Comment: Refer this answer will helpful
[Click Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28739568)