# Android-Webview webpage File-Upload selector not working

Tags: android

In my app `Webview` webpage file upload not working.but in mobile chrome browser it working. what will I need to do for file upload selector working

Here my Code

```
WebView web = findViewById(R.id.webview);
WebSettings websetting = web.getSettings();
websetting.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

web.loadUrl(web_url);
```

In Chrome Browser I click File Selector shows this options

here image reference
[image]

How to add this options in my `webview`
Thanks for help

Comment: have you set permission?

Comment: what kind of permission i need

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: i did not set this permissions

Comment: then how would you get file access?

Comment: still not working

Comment: might be duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34891352/android-choose-file-button-in-webview

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28688946/using-a-webview-to-browse-the-photo-gallery?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this,//we do open selector window for the URLs having "google" in the URI, you can change that :

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {      
                ProgressDialog progressDialog;

                //If you will not use this method url links are open in new brower not in webview
                public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {              

                    // Check if Url contains ExternalLinks string in url 
                    // then open url in new browser
                    // else all webview links will open in webview browser
                    if(url.contains("google")){ 

                        // Could be cleverer and use a regex
                        //Open links in new browser
                        view.getContext().startActivity(
                                new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));

                        // Here we can open new activity

                        return true;

                    } else {

                        // Stay within this webview and load url
                        view.loadUrl(url); 
                        return true;
                    }

                }



                //Show loader on url load
                public void onLoadResource (WebView view, String url) {

                    // if url contains string androidexample
                    // Then show progress  Dialog
                    if (progressDialog == null && url.contains("androidexample") 
                            ) {

                        // in standard case YourActivity.this
                        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(ShowWebView.this);
                        progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
                        progressDialog.show();
                    }
                }

                // Called when all page resources loaded
                public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

                    try{
                        // Close progressDialog
                        if (progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                            progressDialog = null;
                        }
                    }catch(Exception exception){
                        exception.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            });
```

Change action name accordingly e.d. ACTION_SHARE